# What is the difference between querying a database and requesting an endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

Lately I'm trying to learn mongoose but I encountered a code and it confused me.

Why we write async keyword at the beginning of the callback function while we're querying a database? Is it already an asynchronous because of the callback function?

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const subscriber = await Subscriber.find()
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({msg: error.message})
}})
```

And even if it is the way of doing this why don't we also follow the same pattern and put async keyword at the beginning of the callback function in this basic route handling?

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {res.send('Hello from homepage')})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `async` keyword at the beginning of the callback because of the `await` keyword inside of it. Async/await is a feature that let you turn a synchronous function into an asynchronous one (not only javascript has this construct, but also others programming languages). Async/await is syntactic sugar on top of promises and makes asynchronous code easier to write and read. You can find an exhaustive explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: It is okay but what i dont understand is why we don't do same thing to second example. At the end, server takes the request and returns a respond.

Comment: The callback in the second example doesn't contain an asynchronous code, so there is no reason to make this code async. Instead the request to the server is asynchrous, so you should have into the client code something like:

    `async doServerRequest() {
        await axios.get("/")
    }`

If you don't await the server request, your client code doesn't wait for the server response but will continue the execution of the method